# Change Actionbar/Toolbar action text color

Tags: android, xml, android-appcompat

So i'm using appcompat with a toolbar as my actionbar. no matter what attribute I try I can't change the color of Options menu items shown as actions. IE I have the code below and want to change its color when it is displayed as an action only to white.

`<item android:id="@+id/action_login"
        android:title="@string/login_join"
        vendorSearch:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom"
        />`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
<!-- AppTheme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense but seems like your solution to include the item without `android` prefix make it work on android 5